# How to use group_concat

Tags: mysql

I am trying to format a query from a table to look like a matrix that has the date down the left and the results of 3 grouped values under 4 periods during the day.
The Table looks like this:

```
dated     |timed   |beforefood|R  |C |I|
2017-01-01|08:16:00|breakfast |7.3|35|7|
2017-01-01|12:10:00|lunch     |5.3|56|9|
2017-01-01|17:17:00|dinner    |6.8|95|6|
2017-01-01|22:12:00|bedtime   |7.9|0 |0| 

2017-01-02|08:33:00|breakfast |5.6|35|6|
2017-01-02|12:04:00|lunch     |6.8|40|7| 
2017-01-02|17:00:00|dinner    |8.6|50|6|
2017-01-02|22:10:00|bedtime   |9.9|0 |0|

2017-01-03|07:33:00|breakfast |6.2|35|6|
2017-01-03|12:00:00|lunch     |7.3|56|8|
2017-01-03|17:51:00|dinner    |6.4|10|5|
2017-01-03|22:57:00|bedtime   |8.4|0 |0|

To be shown as a Matrix
Date        Breakfast   Lunch   Dinner  Bed
2017-01-01  R-C-I       R-C-I   R-C-I   R-C-I
2017-01-02  R-C-I       R-C-I   R-C-I   R-C-I
2017-01-03  R-C-I       R-C-I   R-C-I   R-C-I
```

In the example above the date 2017-01-01 comes out in the correct order Breakfast --> Beditime
However 2nd and 3rd come out with the RCI group in the correct order but back to front Bedtime --> Breakfast
so breakfast is under bedtime, lunch in under dinner, dinner is under lunch and bedtime is under breakfast

The 4th line is correct and the 5th and 6th are back to front and this is the continuous pattern

Select statement used

```
SELECT  `dated` , GROUP_CONCAT( `R` , ' ', `C` , ' ', `I` ) AS Readings
FROM  `My_Test` 
AND `beforefood` =  'breakfast'
OR  `beforefood` =  'lunch'
OR  `beforefood` =  'dinner'
OR  `beforefood` =  'bedtime'
GROUP BY  `dated`
```

Comment: Changed your tag to _mysql_ from _php_ and _mysqli_. Neither are applicable to this question as the code in question is raw SQL.

Comment: Thanks War10ck I have just noticed that the AND should be a WHERE

Comment: What you are trying to do is called a pivot table. To point you in the right direction, have a look e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table).

Comment: You could also do this using `JOIN`. Select the `breakfast` row and `LEFT JOIN` the other 3 row values. Then you only return 1 row per date.

Comment: Thanks Solarflare and Sean for a quick reply the pivot table looks like the style that I am after so will give it a try.

Comment: Mysqli is a PHP API, so I'm a bit confused